# Is it possible to replace text in properties in Ant's build.xml?

Tags: java, ant

I have a property, app.version, which is set to 1.2.0 (and, of course, always changing) and need to create zip file with name "something-ver-1_2_0". Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task to replace "." with "_" and assign to a new property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <property name="app.version" value="1.2.0"/>

    <pathconvert property="app.version.underscore" dirsep="" pathsep="" description="Replace '.' with '_' and assign value to new property">
        <path path="${app.version}" description="Original app version with dot notation" />

        <!--Pathconvert will try to add the root directory to the "path", so replace with empty string -->
        <map from="${basedir}" to="" />

        <filtermapper>
            <replacestring from="." to="_"/>     
        </filtermapper>

    </pathconvert>

    <echo>${app.version} converted to ${app.version.underscore}</echo>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to [filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) the version number from a file to a property using a regular expression, as suggested in this example:

```
<loadfile srcfile="${main.path}/Main.java" property="version">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp>
            <regexp pattern='^.*String VERSION = ".*";.*$'/>
        </linecontainsregexp>
        <tokenfilter>
            <replaceregex pattern='^.*String VERSION = "(.*)";.*$' replace='\1'/>
        </tokenfilter>
        <striplinebreaks/>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the zip task

```
<zip zipfile="something-ver-${app.version}.zip">
<fileset basedir="${bin.dir}" prefix="bin">
    <include name="**/*" />
</fileset>
<fileset basedir="${doc.dir}" prefix="doc">
    <include name="**/*" />
</fileset></zip>
```

For more information about the zip task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html

Comment: This will get "something-ver-1.2.0.zip", and I need to recieve "something-ver-1_2_0.zip". Maybe, this is impossible? :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the property `app.version` is always changing i *assume* you don't want to hard code it into the properties files, rather pass it when you do the build. Further to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978866/is-it-possible-to-replace-text-in-properties-in-ants-build-xml/1978888#1978888), you can try the following on the command line;

```
ant -f build.xml -Dapp.version=1.2.0
```

changing `app.version` to the one required then.

**Edit:**

Understood better your question from the feedback. [Unfortunately](http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2007/04/22/how-to-do-string-operations-in-ant/) ant does not have string manipulation tasks, you need to write you own [task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html) for this. Here is a close [example](http://xins.sourceforge.net/j2h/latest/org/xins/common/ant/UppercaseTask.java.html).

Comment: pathconvert can be used to perform string manipulation in ANT. 'mapper's also include support for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Properties can't be changed but antContrib vars (http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html ) can.

Here is a macro to do a find/replace all on a var:

```
    <macrodef name="replaceVarText">
        <attribute name="varName" />
        <attribute name="from" />
        <attribute name="to" />
        <sequential>
            <local name="replacedText"/>
            <local name="textToReplace"/>
            <local name="fromProp"/>
            <local name="toProp"/>
            <property name="textToReplace" value = "${@{varName}}"/>
            <property name="fromProp" value = "@{from}"/>
            <property name="toProp" value = "@{to}"/>

            <script language="javascript">
                project.setProperty("replacedText",project.getProperty("textToReplace").split(project.getProperty("fromProp")).join(project.getProperty("toProp")));
            </script>
            <ac:var name="@{varName}" value = "${replacedText}"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
```

Then call the macro like:

```
<ac:var name="newFileName" value="${app.version}"/>
<current:replaceVarText varName="newFileName" from="." to="_" />
<echo>Filename will be ${newFileName}
```