# ant replacetoken with multiple jar file names

Tags: java, ant, jar, token

I have this ant task that creates a webstart jnlp file.

It replaces tokens like @title@ and such from a template file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="@codebase@">
<information>
    <title>@title@</title>
</information>
<resources>
    @jars@
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="@mainclass@"/>
</jnlp>
```

The problem is that I have many jars in my lib/ dir:
Log4J.jar, xpp.jar, resources.jar ...
and 1 jars token.

How can I replace the @jars@ token with the jars file names?
so that the output becomes:

```
<resources>
  <jar href="log4J.jar"/>
  <jar href="xpp.jar"/>
  <jar href="resources.jar"/>
</resources>
```

This is a part of my ant project:

```
<target name="webstart" description="Deploy as jnlp webstart">
    <copy file="template.jnlp" tofile="test.jnlp">
        <filterchain>
            <replacetokens>
                <token key="codebase" value="myCodebase" />
                <token key="title" value="myTitle" />
                <token key="jars" value="jar href="xxx.jar" />
            </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
</target>
<project/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with ant-contrib (thanks to Chad Nouis for the hint with CDATA in properties):

```
<!-- Tricky part is XML content here CDATA Elements are needed, this is the first part-->
<property name="pre"><![CDATA[
  <jar href="]]></property>

<!-- Tricky part is XML content here  CDATA Elements are needed, this is the last part-->
<property name="after"><![CDATA["/>]]></property>

<!-- this will be our temp file-->
<delete file="temp.txt" failonerror="false"/>

<!-- for task from ant-contrib-->
<for param="file">
  <fileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
  <sequential>
    <!-- write it into a file, using var/properties did not work-->
    <echo file="temp.txt" append="true">${pre}@{file}${after}</echo>
  </sequential>
</for>

<!-- load file content in property-->
 <loadfile property="xml.data" srcfile="temp.txt"/>

<!-- finish-->
  <copy file="template.jnlp" tofile="test.jnlp" overwrite="true">
      <filterchain>
          <replacetokens>
              <token key="codebase" value="myCodebase" />
              <token key="title" value="myTitle" />
              <token key="jars" value="${xml.data}" />
          </replacetokens>
      </filterchain>
  </copy>
```

Links:

- [Ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)
- [for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to replace the @jars@ token with literal XML. See if this is what you're after:

```
<target name="run">
    <property name="xml.data"><![CDATA[
        <jar href="log4J.jar"/>
        <jar href="xpp.jar"/>
        <jar href="resources.jar"/>
    ]]></property>

    <copy file="template.jnlp" tofile="test.jnlp">
        <filterchain>
            <replacetokens>
                <token key="codebase" value="myCodebase" />
                <token key="title" value="myTitle" />
                <token key="jars" value="${xml.data}" />
            </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: this seems to be part of the approach, I think he needs the property content to be analysed dynamically according to a fileset.

Comment: Yes, dynamically, I found pathconvert over here[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978866/is-it-possible-to-replace-text-in-properties-in-ants-build-xml)  

and was able to replace the lib path with <a href like so:  

    <filtermapper>  
        <replacestring from="$lib.dir" to="&lt;a href=&quot;"  
    </filtermapper>  

but how would I replace the element end "/>"

Answer (score 0):

As the jnlp file is an xml document you may use the [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/).
For your demand see:
[xml task manual replace](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/#usage.replace)
a little Xpath knowledge won't hurt, see:
http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/