# ANT : What is the simplest way to add version number to built jar?

Tags: java, ant

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myPlugin" default="all">
<target name="artifact.myPlugin:jar" depends="init.artifacts, compile.module.myPlugin" description="Build &#39;myPlugin:jar&#39; artifact">
    <mkdir dir="${artifact.output.myplugin:jar}" />
    <jar destfile="${temp.jar.path.myPlugin.jar}" duplicate="preserve" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <zipfileset file="${basedir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" prefix="META-INF" />
        <zipfileset dir="${myPlugin.output.dir}" />
    </jar>

<!--How would I add a version number to this that reflects my projects version -->
    <copy file="${temp.jar.path.myPlugin.jar}" tofile="${artifact.output.myPlugin:jar}/plugin.company.jar" />
</target>
```

What is the typcial way that people do this?

Example (Pulled from above)

```
<copy file="${temp.jar.path.myPlugin.jar}" tofile="${artifact.output.myPlugin:jar}/plugin.company{version}.jar" />
```

Comment: This [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979137/230513) gets the version from a source file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the ANT [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html) task.

```
<project name="myPlugin" default="all">

    <property name="version" value="1.0"/>

    <target...
        <buildnumber/>

        <jar destfile="/path/to/jar/myjar-${version}.${build.number}.jar" ...
            ...
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

Each build will generate a unique release number:

- myjar-1.0.0
- myjar-1.0.1
- myjar-1.0.2
- ..

Comment: @Mrshll187 That indicates the default target to be invoked if you don't specify anything on the commandline. I'd recommend reading the "Using Apache ANT" section of the ANT manual http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

Comment: Thanks greatly for the response!

Comment: No bother. There are lots of options to set the build number of your release. You asked for the simplest one. If your build is automated (using Jenkins?) then the build server will often provide an incrementing build number which you could access as an environment variable.

Comment: So I would need to follow and ask. How would you have this number be produced by an SVN version of the project which it resides? And also how do you get this time format to show military time

Comment: I recommend not using subversion for your release number. Instead let your build determine the number and then use this to label/tag your code in the SCM. My reasoning is outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879918/extract-value-from-string-using-ant-contrib-propertyregex/12882762#12882762

Comment: @Mrshll187 What time format? Do you mean generate a timestamp? Checkout the tstamp ANT task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html

Comment: I seen that webpage but I didn't see how to turn the time into Miltiary time. Any suggestions? THanks

Comment: @Mrshll187 I would suggest posting a new question, and perhaps a specific example of "military time". Formats supported by Java documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html